# Advanced replace

Tags: python, replace

I have a big file (2GB) containing text, i need to replace in each line (each line is individual), all the substrings of a token present in the row (at an undefined position) and identified by the prefix KEYWORD_ID/ with the token and the original word:

Example:

```
This is an example of the KEYWORD_ID/Replace_Command that is given as an input, 
replace command should be replaced
```

The output should look like:

```
This is an example of the KEYWORD_ID/Replace_Command that is given as an input, 
KEYWORD_ID/Replace_Command replace command should be replaced
```

In a row could be present many KEYWORD_ID

Any idea on how to perform this in an efficient way?

Thanks for the help

Comment: 2GB is not that big, can't you just read the file line by line and use `.replace()` or `regex`?

Comment: @Ares 
I have no ideas
I was trying to find a solution but i get stuck on the part of finding the substrings, i don't know how to match Replace_Command with replace command, is any  Kind of regex that allow me to match these 2 string?

Comment: @MutationalMeltdown The problem is not so much the size (i just can't open it with windows, only printed a few lines from python)
Is the part you see in the reply to Ares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2GB is not big at all, just iterate over line by line, and use `regex`

In case of one replace command:

```
import re

str = 'This is an example of the KEYWORD_ID/Replace_Command that is given as an input, replace command should be replaced'

print(re.sub(r'\breplace\b', re.search('KEYWORD_ID/\w+',str).group(), str))

# returns: This is an example of the KEYWORD_ID/Replace_Command that is given as an input, KEYWORD_ID/Replace_Command command should be replaced
```

In case of more, you ll have to iterate over the `re.group`